# How to pass data from controller to model in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs(Express js), and I am working on API's, Right now I am trying to upload image, Image is uploading fine but I want two things

1. I want to pass and validate "shopid" and "image" parameter
2. Image is uploading but how can we pass these data(parameters) to the model for query execution?

Here is my current code

```
     var AddVendorGalleryStorage =   multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
         callback(null, './uploads');
      },
     filename: function (req, file, callback) {
         var sizeOf = require('image-size');
         var sizeOf = require('image-size');
         const originalname = file.originalname;
         const fileExt = originalname.split(".").pop();
         const excatName = originalname.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
         console.log("mimetype is " + file.mimetype); // GETTING FILE EXTENSION NAME
         callback(null, excatName + "-" + Date.now().toString() + "." + fileExt);
        },
    });
    
     var AddVendorGalleryExtensionCheck = (req, file, cb) => {
      const memeT = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
      const restrictToMemeType = ['jpeg','jpg','png','gif'];
      if (restrictToMemeType.includes(memeT)) {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(new Error('sorry invalid meme type'), false);
      }
    };
    var uploadgallery = multer({ storage: AddVendorGalleryStorage,fileFilter: AddVendorGalleryExtensionCheck }).single('userPhoto');
    
    
    
    const addVendorGallery = async (req, res) => {
     uploadgallery(req,res,function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
            }
            res.end("File is uploaded"+req.file.filename);
        });
    
        }
```